# Crash Report Library For C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, crash-reports

Is there any good crash report library for c++ applications like [CrashRptr](http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/) for visual studio 2013? Sadly this library not working properly in visual studio 2013. Also, I don't want library send date over Internet, I want it to work offline.

Comment: Google Crashpad

Comment: wc and BTW here's the link to it's repo: https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/